# What terrible thing will happen if I do <input type="my-custom-type">?

Tags: html, w3c

I'm working on a progressive enhancement that turns an ordinary HTML input into a date field with a datepicker. I could use

```
<input type="date">
```

But a browser's native datepickers don't have all the features I need, so I don't want to use that. Instead, I'm "extending" HTML by inventing my own type.

```
<input type="so-date">
```

There's some JavaScript code that goes through and finds all the `input[type="so-date"]`s and progressively enhances them.

My colleagues are offended by non-compliant use of `type="so-date"`. HTML sometimes provides that an attribute can have an "invalid default value", but does not provide a default for the [type attribute on input](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-input-type).

Regardless of what the spec says, in practice, everyone knows that an invalid value falls through to "text". *(Update: I misread the spec. That's what user agents are supposed to do.)* **So what actual bad things can happen if I make up my own input type?**

Comment: It would not validate probably. Also what's the point? You might as well add `data-type="...."` and target it that way

Comment: Yeah, that's the alternative. It just makes things a bit more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: What you are doing is making things more complicated, if you need to identify these particular inputs, you can add a class even. There are many valid ways of doing it. In the future, when someone else is trouble shooting your code, this will for sure confuse them. It just seems pointless unless you are purposely trying to invalidate the file

Comment: It makes the "cheat sheet" I'm putting together more complicated. (I'm putting together instructions for some T-shaped developers who aren't experts in HTML but can write clean, semantic, accessible HTML if we give them simple guidelines.)

Comment: Do as you wish, but again you are giving instructions to others when your html is invalid. It just seems pointless doing this when there are many other ways of doing the same thing. I am sure the cheat sheet would not be that much more complicated

Comment: I have to give in to my colleagues, so data-type it is. However, I'm still curious whether some really bad thing could happen, and I just hadn't thought about it, and that's why the spec doesn't have an invalid default value. If someone were to reveal that unknown unknown, I'd probably learn something that's applicable to API design in general. You see, *this question isn't really about HTML*.

Comment: If an enumerated value attribute doesn't have a invalid value default, then the missing value default applies for invalid values. So the state of the input will be Text. See the third paragraph of [section 2.4.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#keywords-and-enumerated-attributes). But as Jukka points out, it might not stay an invalid value for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use literally `type="my-custom-type"`, as in the question title, most probably no harm will be done. If you use `type="so-date"` as in the question body, it is possible that some future version of HTML, or some browser, will introduce such an attribute, with a meaning and effect quite different from what you expect now.

The risk might be small, but it is completely pointless: there is nothing you can win, as opposite to using a `class` attribute, for example.

Comment: The "so-" is of course namespace (not the real namespace) designed to make the chance of that happening infinitesimally small. But it's a valid point.

Comment: It seems this is the only actual risk. If the spec against all odds were to actually collide with my namespace in the future, I would have plenty of time to do a search and replace on my code.

Comment: Currently, what people mostly regard as “HTML standard”, is HTML5, which is a draft that may and will change without prior notice, and changes may be implemented fast in browsers. Besides, browsers may implement extensions of their own. These aspects are important enough that other extension mechanisms are recommended instead of adding attribute values of your own (e.g. `class` attributes and `data-*` attributes).

Comment: Yes, the spec is evolving. We have to support a wide variety of browsers that have too many subtle differences to count. These are real problems that we face every day. Fretting over the possibility that someday "so-date" (again, not the real value) might become part of the standard is akin to [flushing 35 million gallons of water because one person peed in the reservoir](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2014/04/17/urine_in_portland_reservoir_how_dangerous_is_pee_in_drinking_water.html).